# If $\hat O f(x) = f(x^2+1)$, is $\hat O$ a linear operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics

If $\hat O f(x) = f(x^2+1)$, is $\hat O$ a linear operator? It seems this follows the condition being linear operator. But think in following way;

$\hat O f(x) = f(x^2+1) = g(x) \Rightarrow$

$\hat O f(x) = g(x)$.

Now, this seems to me $\hat O$ is not linear. If my proposition is wrong, please correct me and try to explain with simple and plain examples.

By the way, Gasiorowicz in his Quantum Physics book (3rd ed.) claims it is a linear operator.

Thank you in advance for your helps.

Comment: It is linear. You have $$\hat{O}(f+g)(x)= (f+g)(x^2+1)= f(x^2+1)+g(x^2+1) = \hat{O}(f)(x)+\hat{O}(g)(x)$$ As this holds for all $x$ you get $\hat{O}(f+g)=\hat{O}(f)+\hat{O}(g)$. Similarly one proves $\hat{O}(\alpha f)=\alpha \hat{O}(f)$ for $\alpha\in \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $D_\hat{O}$ be the set over which the operator $\hat{O}$ is defined.

Let $f(x) = h(x) + g(x)$ with $h,g \in D_\hat{O}$ and thus $f \in D_\hat{O}$. Then, it is :

$$\hat{O}f(x) = f(x^2+1) \Leftrightarrow \hat{O}[(h(x)+g(x)] = h(x^2+1) + g(x^2+1) $$

$$\Leftrightarrow$$

$$\hat{O}[h(x)+g(x)] = \hat{O}h(x) + \hat{O}g(x)$$

Now, for $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ and $f(x) \in D_\hat{O}$, let $g(x) = \lambda f(x)$ which also is $g(x) \in D_\hat{O}$. Then, it is :

$$\hat{O}g(x) = g(x^2+1) =\lambda f(x^2+1) $$

$$\Leftrightarrow$$

$$\hat{O}(\lambda f(x)) = \lambda \hat{O}f(x)$$

Thus, the operator $\hat{O}$ respects the operation of addition and the  operation of scalar multiplication $\implies$ $\hat{O}$ is a linear operator.

**Regarding your proposition :** It doesn't really make any sense. You just let $g(x)$ be the function yielded by the operator. This doesn't say anything about linearity.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your answer while typing.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Absolutely no problem at all mate !

Comment: Thanks to both of you.

\begin{array} { l } { O f ( x ) = f ( x ) + x ^ { 2 } } \\ { O f ( x ) = [ f ( x ) ] ^ { 2 } } \\ { O f ( x ) = f \left( 3 x ^ { 2 } + 1 \right) } \\ { O f ( x ) = [ d f ( x ) / d x ] ^ { 3 } } \\ { O f ( x ) = d f ( x ) / d x - 2 f ( x ) } \\ { O f ( x ) = \lambda f ( x ) } \end{array}

I think the above examples mislead me. Since the right side does not include the $\hat O$ operator.  

Everything is clear now.

Comment: @hesap No problem. If you consider your question answered, you can click on the "tick" button below the vote button on my answer box to check it as the accepted answer.

Comment: The system warns me: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: @hesap Oh ! You need more rep to vote. Does it not let you accept the answer as well ?